# Error Undefined offset in library codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I created dynamic menu with Dynamic_menu.php library. Inside file I use active record

```
$query = $this->ci->db->get($table);
```

for calling table, but when I change $query to

```
$this->ci->db->select('*');
$this->ci->db->from('menu_master_new_copy');
$this->ci->db->where('parent_id', 0);
$query = $this->ci->db->get();
```

I get error:

> Undefined offset

How to fix it ?

Comment: parent_id should not be 0

Comment: but before i try in sql SELECT * FROM `menu_master_new_copy` WHERE parent_id='0'; and this work, or when i change 0 to be 1 or any in codeigniter, query still error Undefined offset

Comment: Undefined offset means that you're trying to access an array index that doesn't exist. This error is likely being displayed due to whatever you're doing with the results.

Comment: post the line where you are getting this error and how you are accessing the data

Comment: Is that the complete error message you are getting? Just "Undefined Offset" all on it's own ?

Comment: Ok so you can check SQL Statements... What does echo $this->ci->db->last_query(); after your "get" give you... That is the generated SQL. So try that out and see what result that gives you. Only asking to show how to start debugging.

Comment: Have you try to not use `$this->ci->db->select('*');` ? The query should already return all columns if no name are specified